# Air conditioner fan not starting

Tags: motor, fan

I have a problem with my air conditioner fan not starting. As seen from the schematic below, when I test for voltage between the brown and black wires, I get 0 V (this is the problem). The indoor unit isn't sending the control signal to turn the fan on. The compressor powers on fine though. When I connect the brown and red wires together (since red is giving power fine), the circuit breaker trips, maybe too much inrush current since motor and compressor turn on together?

I then powered the fan separately and it works (fan or capacitor is not faulty).

- Could there be a relay or something controlling the fan that's not giving power from brown cable?

[image: Schematic]

Comment: You would have to check the indoor unit, possibly posting a picture of the control board. It's probably controlled by a triac and it might have died.

Comment: Can you measure the capacitance of the motor run capacitors? If not, measure the voltage across them when energized?

Comment: @winny, I started the motor separately and it turns on and runs. I understand the capacitor is responsible for starting the motor, if it was faulty wouldn't the motor not start ?, thanks

Comment: Suggest migrating this to [DIY](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: Yes, there could be a relay or something that is not giving power from the brown cable> That certainly seems to be the most likely problem.

Comment: I see an 'orientation valve' - is this a heat pump? If so, the power to the outside fan goes through a relay on a defrost control board, to allow the compressor to run and not the fan during the defrost cycle.

Comment: You've done a good job of documenting the outdoor unit and established that the problem is likely with the indoor unit, so show us the relevant information for the control board/circuit/apparatus on the other end of the brown wire.  Part of what the control unit does is start the devices separately to spread out their inrush currents.